# how to make arabic keyboard direction still LTR in ios

Tags: ios, text, arabic, hebrew, direction

i need some help about arabic & hebrew text direction. In UITextview IOS, if i use arabic or hebrew keyboard , the text direction change into RTL automatically. And then, if i set in into LTR, and i press enter, the direction change into RTL again. Is there any way to set this direction still LTR when i use arabic & hebrew text??

I have read about

```
- (UITextPosition *)positionWithinRange:(UITextRange *)range farthestInDirection:(UITextLayoutDirection)direction;
```

but i'm not sure how to use it. Is this method can help me to solved this problem? is there anyone who face the same problem with me? Can you share the solution, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set alignment for your textfield in xib there are three option in your text field for alignment left to right,centre & Right to left You can select any one of them and assign alignment for your text field 
-Thanx

Comment: thank you for your answer, i have set that allignment into left. But the problem is about direction not allignment. CMIIW